# How to remove s specific part of string in php

Tags: php, regex

I am fetching data from a database as a string like **02-feb-1990**  I want to  remove all the characters from the string, and have only date of year  means **1990**.

How can I achieve this in PHP using regex or any other method

Comment: You can use php's  `trim` functions.

Comment: Why don't you Google for it first? String functions like substr... or regex to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $input = "02-feb-1990";     
    echo $year = substr($input, -4);

?>
```

Output:

```
1990
```

If you want to use regex:

```
<?php

    $input = "02-feb-1990";

    preg_match_all("/\d{4}$/", $input, $matches);
    print_r($matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 1990 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve a 4 digit year from dd-mmm-yyyy using regex, you can use the following:

```
$date = "02-feb-1990"
preg_match('/\d{4}/', $date, $year);
echo $year[0];
```

The above will match the first 4 digit number you come across, which in this instance, will always be the 4-digit year.